# Changing cell type in DGV from ComboBox to TextBox only works for row 0?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have struggled all day trying to make my DataGridView behave. I'm using the following code to change a  ComboBox cell to a TextBox, when user selects entry

It works beatifully for row 0, but for all other rows, the ComboBox remains on the screen, even though debugging says it's a TextBox cell! (inspecting CurrentCell).

Does anybody have a clue?

Here's a snippet:

```
void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cb = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        if (cb.SelectedIndex == 0 && dataGridViewReceivers.CurrentCell is DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
        {
            cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            dataGridViewReceivers.CellLeave -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridViewReceivers_CellLeave);
            dataGridViewReceivers.EndEdit();

            // Change to editing mode
            int row = dataGridViewReceivers.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            dataGridViewReceivers[0, row] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dataGridViewReceivers[0, row].Value = "";
            dataGridViewReceivers.BeginEdit(false);
            dataGridViewReceivers.RefreshEdit();

            dataGridViewReceivers.CellLeave += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridViewReceivers_CellLeave);
            cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged); 
        }
    }
```

New rows are added using a BindingSource.AddNew().

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

When I call the code to replace the cell object, outside the event handler - it works! This indicates that it is worth trying a delegate...

**EDIT:**

**Problem solved**
It turns out that if I remove the focus from the DGV during the replacement, it works! Simply momentarily setting the focus to a button, and back again does the trick!

Comment: A delegate wont solve your problem.

Comment: No, you're right. See my last edit!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the DGV does not allow me to change the cell type when it has focus. Unselecting the cell is not enough - focus needs to be removed from the control.

This looks like a .NET bug!...